# Подбор параметров для построения карты глубины openCV

Tags: opencv

Есть откалиброванная стереопара с помощью которой я строю карту глубины используя алгоритм StereoSGBM из библиотеки openCV. Алгоритм предусматривает возможность настройки через встроенные параметры: setBlockSize, setDisp12MaxDiff, setMinDisparity, setNumDisparities, setSpeckleRange, setSpeckleWindowSize, setMode и т.д. При использовании стандартного примера из opencv карта глубины строится отличная, но если использовать свои изображения то карта глубины строится неверно.

Отсюда вопрос - как правильно подобрать значения вышеперечисленных параметров чтобы построить карту глубины? Существуют ли какие нибудь инструкции по подбору параметров? Существуют ли программы автоматического подбора этих параметров?